# Installing a game via GitHub onto Google Colab

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install a python game I am working on onto Google Colab, via GitHub. It has been working fine for the past few weeks, but today I got this error, even though I didn’t change anything. Any ideas, please?

The code I run:

```
# Install
!git clone --depth 1 --branch master https://github.com/Nokkla/AIDungeonClone
%cd AIDungeonClone/
!./install.sh
from IPython.display import clear_output
#clear_output()
#print("Installation Complete!")
```

Output:

```
Cloning into 'AIDungeonClone'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 62, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (62/62), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (51/51), done.
remote: Total 62 (delta 8), reused 50 (delta 5), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (62/62), done.
/content/AIDungeonClone
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-pip-whl python3.6-venv
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pip-whl python3-venv python3.6-venv
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,660 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,901 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 python-pip-whl all 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1 [1,653 kB]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 python3.6-venv amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 python3-venv amd64 3.6.7-1~18.04 [1,208 B]
Fetched 1,654 kB in 0s (14.0 MB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python3.6/python3.6-venv_3.6.9-1~18.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing this

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  && sudo apt-get update
```

and then continue with you installation commands.